# Python-peewee get last saved row

Tags: python, orm, peewee

is there a way how to obtain last saved row in database while using peewee with all its attributes?
Let's say I do this:

```
user = User.create(
    email = request.json['email'],
    nickname = request.json['nickname'],
    password = request.json['password'],
    salt = "salt"
)
```

But `user.id` is `None` and the only attributes I can get are those specified above.
I could call `select()` method but isn't there there any faster way?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, if User has a primary-key field for "id", the "id" will be populated automatically upon creation / save.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
User.select().order_by(User.id.desc()).get()
```

This will get the last-created user assuming the IDs is an auto-incrementing integer (the default).

Or if you want to get e.g. last created customer (user), you can write it like this:

```
User.select().where(User.type == "customer").order_by(User.id.desc()).get()
```

If you want to get the last *saved* user, you need to add a timestamp to indicate when the user is saved.

---

Update:

Peewee also now supports `RETURNING` clause for Postgres database. You can add a `RETURNING` clause to any `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query. Check out the docs:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#returning-clause
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=returning#InsertQuery.returning

Comment: this throws error if there is no row i.e if table is empty !

Comment: @ChangZhao You could wrap it in try/except and call it a day!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of re-querying the DB, one alternative is the following:

```
u = User(email="..", nickname="..", password="..", salt="..")
u.save()

# at this point, peewee inserted the entry in the DB,
# and updated all relevant fields (including the ID).
# For example, you can do the following:

print "ID of last-created user: %d" % u.id
```

For complex, multi-threaded systems, I think this a better alternative.

Comment: Peewee also now supports `RETURNING` (postgres only), which works on INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries. [Docs here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#returning-clause).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your `User` model looks like this:

```
class User(Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = TextField(unique=True)
    nickname = TextField()
    password = TextField()
    salt = TextField()
```

But peewee doesn't know how to handle autoincrementing fields unless you use its PrimaryKeyField class:

```
class User(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    email = TextField(unique=True)
    nickname = TextField()
    password = TextField()
    salt = TextField()
```

This wasn't documented anywhere I could find. [Source](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/194).